# Swift Combine erase array of publishers into AnyCancellable

Tags: swift, combine

Is it possible to fire multiple requests which return a `Publisher` and be able to cancel them without `sink`?

I would like to combine the requests into a single cancellable reference or store each one if possible without `sink` (code below). Is this possible?

```swift
func fetchDetails(for contract: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, Error>
```

Fire Multiple requests and store

```swift
  @State var cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    let promises = items.map {
      self.fetchFeed.fetchDetails(for: $0.contract)
    }
    
    Publishers.MergeMany(promises)
      .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { _ in }) // ** is this required?
      .store(in: &cancellable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what `fetchDetails` does to create the publisher. Almost every publisher provided by Apple has no side effects until you subscribe to it. For example, the following publishers have no side effects until you subscribe to them:

- `NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher` (returned by `NSObject.publisher(for:options:)`
- `NotificationCenter.Publisher` (returned by `NotificationCenter.publisher(for:object:)`
- `Timer.TimerPublisher` (returned by `Timer.publishe(every:tolerance:on:in:options:)`
- `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` (returned by `URLSession.dataTaskPublisher(for:)`
- The synchronous publishers like `Just`, `Empty`, `Fail`, and `Sequence.Publisher`.

In fact, the **only** publisher that has side effects on creation, as far as I know, is `Future`, which runs its closure immediately on creation. This is why you'll often see the `Deferred { Future { ... } }` construction: to avoid immediate side effects.

So, if the publisher returned by `fetchDetails` behaves like most publishers, you must subscribe to it to make any side effects happen (like actually sending a request over the network).

Comment: Timer goes even further of course. It has no effect until you hit it over the head. :)